# Convert normal SQL query to Zend_Db?

Tags: database, zend-framework

I cant convert this below query to Zend_Db:

```
SELECT `mfaq`.* FROM `m_faq` AS `mfaq`
WHERE (mfaq.delete_flg <> 'D' OR mfaq.delete_flg IS NULL)
AND ((mfaq.title like '%$title%')
OR (mfaq.title like '%$title%')
AND (mfaq.title like '%$title%') 
OR (mfaq.title like '%$title%'))
ORDER BY `create_date` DESC
```

Some help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to have created dbtable model:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Mfaq extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'm_faq';
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
$table = new Application_Model_DbTable_Mfaq();

$select = $table->getAdapter()->select()
            ->from(array('mfaq'=>$table->info(Zend_Db_Table::NAME)))
            ->where("( mfaq.delete_flg <> 'D'")
            ->orWhere("mfaq.delete_flg IS NULL )")
            ->where("( mfaq.title like ?", "%$title%")
            ->orWhere("mfaq.title like ? ", "%$title%")
            ->where(" mfaq.title like ?", "%$title%")
            ->orWhere("mfaq.title like ? )", "%$title%")
            ->order("create_date DESC");

// echo $select; // shows your sql
$results = $select->query()->fetchAll();
```

I hope, you take into account that AND have higher priority than OR.